# While looping through JDBC resultset what happens if we lose network?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

If you running a JDBC program from your laptop which is connected to office network over wi-fi. 
What happens if network is lost while looping through ( JDBC ) result set? 
I noticed java.sql.Connection & Statement objects have timeout. But result set has no time out setting.

```
ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
while (rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt(1);
    // use this and run some biz logic.
}
```

I noticed program keep waiting for next results forever. how to make it throw exception ? Has any one experienced this? What did you do ?

Comment: I'd guess the behaviour depends on the DBMS and the JDBC driver. What did you use here?

Comment: Javadoc of [`setQueryTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout-int-) says: *JDBC driver implementations **may** also apply this limit to `ResultSet` methods (consult your driver vendor documentation for details).* So it's entirely up to the driver if and how to control `ResultSet` timeout. If not controlled by `setQueryTimeout()`, it could be a connection property. Or you could be out of luck. As it says: *Consult your driver vendor documentation*.

Comment: I am using Oracle. I noticed setQueryTimeout and guessing Oracle implemented it. Will test this and update the results. I am using a special SQL which is reading CDC info. so the result set gives results continuously.

Comment: I want to correct: when working with a VPN connection and VPN gone, so network is still on but connection to sql server is down. in such cases I noticed resultset is kind of waiting in forever mode.

Answer (score 0):

ResultSet will not be longer usable, but what you can do is:

You have two options:

First: (and I suggest) using **Transactions**, As [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) says:

> When a connection is created, it is in auto-commit mode. This means
>   that each individual SQL statement is treated as a transaction and is
>   automatically committed right after it is executed. (To be more
>   precise, the default is for a SQL statement to be committed when it is
>   completed, not when it is executed. A statement is completed when all
>   of its result sets and update counts have been retrieved. In almost
>   all cases, however, a statement is completed, and therefore committed,
>   right after it is executed.)

And in your case you should execute once after all of your statement are completed, in case of network failure or any error in one statement all of your statements will rolled back

Example: [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

```
public void updateCoffeeSales(HashMap<String, Integer> salesForWeek)
    throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement updateSales = null;
    PreparedStatement updateTotal = null;
    String updateString =
        "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
        "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
    String updateStatement =
        "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
        "set TOTAL = TOTAL + ? " +
        "where COF_NAME = ?";
    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
        updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : salesForWeek.entrySet()) {
            updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
            updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
            updateSales.executeUpdate();
            updateTotal.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
            updateTotal.setString(2, e.getKey());
            updateTotal.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                con.rollback();
            } catch(SQLException excep) {
                JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(excep);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (updateSales != null) {
            updateSales.close();
        }
        if (updateTotal != null) {
            updateTotal.close();
        }
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
}
```

Second: You may have to buffer all the results before the connection was lost but take care of closing the result set, statement and connection